# How to get a window with specified resolution system settings independent

Tags: windows, user-interface, testing

I am testing a GUI (Swing based) interface and need to do it with special screen resolution. Is there any way to keep original system resolution and display the window of the application under test with specified resolution (system independent) ? Any tool for that kind of things?

Thanks,
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

You can use VMWare or a similar tool to run a virtual machine.  These usually allow you to specify the screen resolution.

Comment: Any idea how to do it without VMWear?

Comment: No.  I don't think it can be done on one monitor without VMWare or one of its competitors.  

I guess you could use a second monitor, with a second graphics card.